# How to ensure containing element is full page height, no matter the number of dynamic children

Tags: css, angular, sass

I am trying to get a containing div that is full page-height to expand so that is is always equal to the height of its content.

The overall structure is

*search.html*

```
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="body">
      <app-results></app-results>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*results.html*

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let c of content; let index = index">
  <h1 class="h">{{index}}</h1>
</div>
```

I have tried setting the `.outer-container` to `[display: inline-flex][1];` which works really well. Until more `card`s are added dynamically to the view. At that point, the containing element remains at the same place it was before the dynamic content was inserted, right at the viewport's previous bottom.

I've also tried various permutations of `height: auto`, and `height: 100%` on the entire tree of elements, but it seems like when I get the parent's height to work correctly with a batch of children that extends beyond the page, its height shrinks when it is one element; and when it looks good when there is just one element, the parent looks to short when more children are added which overflow the page height.

Also, in my app `overflow: auto` produces a double scrollbar, so that won't work.

#### How can I get the full height to persist no matter the number of elements?

[More detailed StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bc72te-ompc5s?file=app%2Fsearch%2Fsearch.component.scss) You have to click the "search" link to get to the correct route. (I added angular router to be sure my reproduction was accurate as possible)

Comment: Have you tried height:100vh ?

Comment: @alotropico That would only work with a small set of elements. As soon as children occupy more vertical space than 100vh, the container would be "cut" at 100vh. min-height:100vh doesn't work either, if that's what you meant, as there is also other stuff at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your StackBlitz.  I assume that the issue is that when you click 'toggle' the pink background does not extend.   If so, all you need to do is add `overflow: auto;` to your CSS as shown below.  I tried it on your StackBlitz and it worked.

```css
.outer-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: pink;
  overflow: auto;
  .inner-container {
    height: inherit;
  }
}
```

The overflow property specifies what should happen if content overflows an element's box.

Answer (score 0):

I changed a couple lines on your stackblitz and it seems to be working how you described. You can make the .outer-container height `fit-content` and min-height `100%`:

```css
.outer-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: fit-content;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: pink;
  .inner-container {
    height: inherit;
  }
}
```